# How to switch source file and line number for error reporting based on #line-directives in Antlr4?

Tags: antlr4

Parsing a language with an `#include`-feature similar to C/C++, I have decided to emit a `#line`-directive from a dedicated preprocessor (not created by antlr) into a recognizer generated by Antlr4.  Now I wonder, how to use that information in the parser to update the source file name and line information used by the antlr-generated code to create error reporting referring to the actual source and include files (instead of referring to the fully preprocessed artefact).  Is there an interface in the generated lexer supporting this use case?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing like this in ANTLR4. It can process one block of text at a time and doesn't know about multiple blocks, let alone files.

A possible approach would be to handle the individual blocks (files) and compute the correct error line numbers yourself in a post processing phase (usually the semantic phase).